Oxidization of Octane
I asked a question yesterday, once to one of our PhD scientists and once to my favorite AI Claude. It was:
"If we bubble dry air through octane at 25degC does it change its composition or oxidize over time?"
PhD said no change, Claude said it is going to degrade into multiple products. Now, who is correct?
Added details: It seems we use 98%+ pure octane. So, if the octane evaporates in may concentrate impurities. However, we start every set of tests with new octane. We measure the purity by measuring the speed of sound in the vapor. We can resolve speed of sound to about 1 part in quarter million.
It could be a supplier problem, and I assume we could increase the purity but am interested to know whether oxidation products might be contaminating the vapor stream

It does not noticably reacts before it rather quickly evaporates.  (Claude 3.5 Sonnet supports that too.)

Yes, but we are working with very pure octane and any change in composition results in analytical errors. We bubble air through it to work with the vapor

I think you should provide more details of the given scenario, otherwise mysteries of the question itself add one more layer to the problem. // In chemistry and generally in science, there is not change/no change. There is a change above or below a considered threshold that can be anything from detection to significance for a given scenario. What  is threshold for impurities and octane content?// I would be more concerned about the purity of the air. //  Unless there is some published experimental check, I am afraid you have to do such a check yourself wit fresh and long time used octane. //

There can be also accumulation of less volatile impurities in the octane itself. Depending on the relative rate of evaporation.

@Poutnik Yes. We have already encountered that problem. I will edit the question to provide more details

Absent any other reagents or sources of ignition/radicals (such as UV light) no oxidation will occur.

98%+ pure is by no means very pure, unless you gravely underestimated it.
